# Management too-hands off and workplace is chaotic

Tags: colleagues, project-management, teamwork, team-role

Management in this company is almost non-existent. There are no procedures or processes and everything is up in the air. When new people starts there is no orientation process or training at all. Every time they hire a new person the person is not exposed to any common knowledge or practices.

Anyways, this results in a LOT of stress and chaos. I'm just a young, junior but other places I've worked at were much more efficient and organized. How can I say something without pointing fingers or causing wars?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options here: you can start actively working to make the place less chaotic, or you can find another employer.

You probably won't get far trying to tell others things are a mess -- likely people already know but are too busy or don't care.

Since you say there's no on-boarding process, you can create it, based on your experience. Sometimes when there is no one responsible for day-to-day management, one can become a de facto leader through simply getting things done.

This can be a good way to gain experience, but is risky -- you may be shut down by others who consider you too junior to be doing such things. In that case, your only other choice might be to leave.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with mcknz. If you think a process needs fixing, fix it.

But don't do it on your own. It will be harder to get it right on your own, and it will be harder to get acceptance. If you want to fix the onboarding process, tell the hiring manager what you think is missing from the onboarding process, and that you would like to work on the onboarding process with the next new hire. If the hiring manager refuses, they would also dismiss any onboarding process you create out of your own initiative.

With anything you fix, start small. The bigger you go, the more likely that you will be stalled by incompetent management. If you want to introduce a knowledge repository (Wiki), you will probably not get approval for a company-wide wiki. But you should be able to get a local team wiki up and running, if you can convince your teammates to use and contribute to the team wiki.

Comment: I agree he shouldn't do it on his own, but sometimes you have to show progress/results when asking. I believe the hiring manager would be less likely to refuse if that means shutting down an active and concrete process or outcome. But that's why it's risky -- you may end up doing work for nothing. At the same time, one usually learns something by working at a problem, even if it's ultimately throwaway.